# Can I give my own MIB any OID that I want? Is there a convention to application MIB OID?

Tags: snmp, snmpd, oid

I created a scalar MIB for my application, monitor request_queue_size.
I followed the [write MIB tutorial](http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/TUT:Writing_a_MIB_Module) . The OID there is a long hierarchical OID.
I wonder if I can give a short hierarchical OID like 1.1 .
Is there any convention?

My application is hosted on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can have a look at the [Cisco Field Manual Router Configuration](https://flylib.com/books/en/1.298.1.149/1/). It shows you the top-level MIB tree. When referring to OID like: 1.3.6.1.4.1.8072, you are referring to:

```
iso.org.dod.internet.private.enterprise.your_company
```

So, this is the convention used. Otherwise, you may have conflict with existing MIBs.

Note that `your_company` is *not* just some number you can make up yourself — It is an IANA-Assigned [Private Enterprise Number (PEN)](https://pen.iana.org/pen/PenApplication.page).  If your company does not already have a PEN you must register for one.

Comment: so for my private mib i can give 1.3.6.1.4.1.1.1.0, where the suffix of 1.1.0  , 1- my company, 1- my scalar - reuqest_pending , 0- scalar vlaue

Comment: @user1495181: [Here](http://www.alvestrand.no/objectid/1.3.6.1.4.1.html), you can find the list of registered companies.

Comment: @user1495181 Do not just pick any Enterprise number. Register for one ***FREE*** from IANA: http://pen.iana.org/pen/PenApplication.page

Comment: @Khaled The official list of Enterprise IDs is: http://www.iana.org/assignments/enterprise-numbers

Comment: @ChrisS: Thanks. I just picked any link to show that there are already many reserved numbers.